# CONCAT_WS in sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, sqlobject

In my sqlobject implementation I have the following line:

```
members = Member.select("CONCAT_WS(' ', member.first_name, member.last_name, member.personal_code_number, member.mail) like " + Member.sqlrepr('%' + query + '%'))
```

I want to convert that to using sqlalchemy but haven't found a way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```python
members = session.query(Member).filter(
    func.CONCAT_WS(' ', Member.first_name, Member.last_name, Member.personal_code_number, Member.mail)
    .like('%' + query + '%')
)
```