# How to effectively use func.isnull in sql alchemy to get the two strings joined comma separated?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Below is the code I have as part of a sqlalchemy query. Most of the time fist name is null. But Here in the case of below statement, always returns last name with a comma. Eg: `lastName`,
How to add comma only if there's first name?

```
(func.isnull(
            prv.last_name,
            '') +
         ', ' +
         func.isnull(
            prv.first_name,
            '')).label('MyName')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what database you use behind sqlalchemy but I believe what you are looking for is an equivalent of MySQL's [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

> CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special
>   form of CONCAT(). The first argument is the separator for the rest of
>   the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be
>   concatenated. The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the
>   arguments. If the separator is NULL, the result is NULL.

Using it in sqlalchemy should be a matter of calling

`func.CONCAT_WS(',', prv.last_name,prv.first_name)` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914464/concat-ws-in-sqlalchemy))